# How to work around maximum execution time when uploading to S3 Bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am using the [S3-for-Google-Apps-Script](https://github.com/eschultink/S3-for-Google-Apps-Script) library to export full attachments from Gmail to an S3 bucket. I changed the S3 code to upload the actual content of the attachment rather than an encoded string, as detailed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61491801/upload-image-png-file-from-google-app-script-to-s3-bucket).

However, when attempting to upload an attachment approximately > 5 MB, apps script throws the following error: "Maximum Execution Time Exceeded". I used timestamps to measure the difference in time to ensure that the time issue occurred in the `s3.putObject(bucket,objectKey,file)` function.

It might be also helpful to note that for a file barely over the limit, it still gets uploaded to my s3 bucket, but apps script returns that the execution time has been exceeded (30 seconds) to the user, disrupting user flow.

---

**Reproducible Example**

This is basically a simple button that scrapes a current email for all attachments, if they are pdf's then it calls the export function. and it exports those attachments to our s3 instance. the problem is that when the file > 5mb, it throws the error:

> "exportHandler exceeded execution time"

If you're trying to reproduce this be aware that you need to copy an instance of [s3 for gas](https://github.com/eschultink/S3-for-Google-Apps-Script) and initialize that as a separate library in apps script with the changes made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61492304/8219838).

In order to link the libraries, go to file>libraries, and add the respective library id, version, and development mode in the google apps script console. You'll also need to save your AWS access key and secret key in your property service cache, as detailed in the library documentation.

1. An initial button that triggers an export of a single attachment on the current Gmail thread:

```
export default function testButton() {
  const Card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  const exportButtonSection = CardService.newCardSection();
  const exportWidget = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText('Export File')
    .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('exportHandler'));
  exportButtonSection.addWidget(exportWidget);
  Card.addSection(exportButtonSection);
  return Card.build();
}
```

2. Export an attachment to a specified s3 bucket. Note that S3Modified is an instance of the s3 for google apps script that is modified in accordance to the post outlined above, it's a separate Apps Script file, `s3.putObject` is where it takes a long time to process an attachment (this is where the error occurs I think).
3. credentials initialize your s3 `awsAccessKey` and `awsBucket`, and can be stored in `PropertiesService`.

```
function exportAttachment(attachment) {
  const fileName = attachment.getName();
  const timestamp = Date.now();
  const credentials = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperties();
  const s3 = S3Modified.getInstance(credentials.awsAccessKeyId, credentials.awsSecretAccessKey);
  s3.putObject(credentials.awsBucket, fileName, attachment, { logRequests: true });
  const timestamp2 = Date.now();
  Logger.log('difference: ', timestamp2 - timestamp);
}
```

4. This gets all the attachments that are PDFs in the current email message, this function is pretty much the same as the one on the apps script site for handling Gmail attachments, this specifically looks for pdf's though (not a requirement for the code):

```
function getAttachments(event) {
  const gmailAccessToken = event.gmail.accessToken;
  const messageIdVal = event.gmail.messageId;

  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(gmailAccessToken);
  const mailMessage = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageIdVal);

  const thread = mailMessage.getThread();
  const messages = thread.getMessages();
  const filteredAttachments = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i += 1) {
    const allAttachments = messages[i].getAttachments();
    for (let j = 0; j < allAttachments.length; j += 1) {
      if (allAttachments[j].getContentType() === 'application/pdf') {
        filteredAttachments.push(allAttachments[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  return filteredAttachments;
}
```

5. the global handler that gets attachments and exports them to the s3 bucket when the button is clicked:

```
function exportHandler(event) {
  const currAttachment = getAttachments(event).flat()[0];
  exportAttachment(currAttachment);
}
global.export = exportHandler;
```

To be absolutely clear, the bulk of the time is being processed in the second code sample (`exportAttachment`), since that is where the object is being put into the s3 application.

The timestamps help log how much time that function takes, test it with a 300kb file, you'll get 2 seconds, 4mb 20 seconds, >5mb approx 30 seconds. This part contributes the most to the max execution time.

---

So this is what leads me to my question, why do I get the maximum execution time exceeded error and how can I fix it? Here are my two thoughts on potential solutions:

1. Why does the execution limit occur? The [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) say that the runtime limit for a custom function is 30 seconds, and the runtime limit for the script is 6 minutes. 
   After some research, I only found custom function mentions in the context of AddOns in Google Sheets, but the function where I'm getting the error is a global function (so that it can be recognized by a callback) in my script. Is there a way to change it to not be recognized as a custom function so that I'm not limited to the 30-second execution limit?
2. Now, how can I work around this execution limit? Is this an issue with the recommendation to modify the S3 library in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61491801/upload-image-png-file-from-google-app-script-to-s3-bucket)? Essentially, the modification suggests that we export the actual bytes of the attachment rather than the encoded string. 
   This definitely increases the load that Apps Script has to handle which is why it increases the execution time required. How can I work around this issue? Is there a way to change the S3 library to improve processing speed?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions posts on this site should be limited to ask one question, otherwise they could be closed as "need more focus". Regarding why you script is throwing the execution time limit, please add add an [mcve].

Comment: hey @Rubén - i've sampled some test code to be a minimal reproducible example. in order to test it out, some credentials need to be posted in the propertyservice cache, and the s3-apps-script library needs to be modified and posted as a separate library too. i've tried to make the instructions both comprehensive and clear, while also making teh question clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the first question

From https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/actions#callback_functions

> Warning: The Apps Script Card service limits callback functions to a maximum of 30 seconds of execution time. If the execution takes longer than that, your add-on UI may not update its card display properly in response to the Action.

Regarding the second question

On the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49536375/1595451) to [Google Apps Script Async function execution on Server side](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49114450/1595451) it's suggested a "hack": Use an "open link" action to call something that can run asynchronously the task that will requiere a long time to run.

Related

- [How to use HtmlService in Gmail add-on using App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47477246/1595451)
- [Handling Gmail Addon Timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51162945/1595451)
- [Can't serve HTML on the Google Apps Script callback page in a GMail add-on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59860133/1595451)

---

Answer to rev 1.

Regarding the first question

In Google Apps Script, a *custom function* is a function to be used in a Google Sheets formula. There is no way not extend this limit. Reference https://developers.google.com/app-script/guides/sheets/functions

`onOpen` and `onEdit` simple triggers has also a 30 seconds execution time limit. Reference https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Functions being executed from the Google Apps Script editor, a custom menu, an image that has assigned the function, installable triggers, client side code, Google Apps Script API has an execution time limit of 6 minutes for regular Google accounts (like those that have a @gmail.com email address) by the other hand G Suite accounts have a 30 minutes limit.

Comment: Why is there a 30 second limit on the execution time for my function if it isn't used as a Google Sheets formula? If it's not a custom function, it should have a 6 minute limit right?

Comment: added --- sorry about that, please let me know what other information would be helpful too. w.r.t to your suggestion, i don't use the onOpen or onEdit trigger, rather the function is being executed from the google apps script editor, any reason why that would still be subject to a 30 second limit? thank you for that clarification though.

Comment: @nirmalb I added the specific reference regarding the 30 seconds limit for the Card Service.

Comment: got it- curious to see if in that related post, is there any way of handling files that are too large? or will i have to put a file size restriction on it and check for operations > 30 seconds? i'm guessing there isn't another way, but not sure. I also saw that someone recommended using client side HTMLService, is it possible to call that from a card in the gmail addon ui? Or, not at all?